# Using different SSL certificate on IIS websites with same port number

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

I was wondering if it's possible to use different certificate on websites that have the same port number. I have about 15 websites that are sharing the same port number `443`.

When I change a certificate of one, be it via Powershell or directly through IIS, it changes the certificate of all the other websites on that port. However, if I create a test website on a different port, say `441`, IIS allows me to have different certificates on them.

I was wondering if it's possible (preferably via Powershell) to have my IIS sites created and configured in such a way that they can have different SSL certificates assigned to them?

Comment: Thsi has nothing to do with Powershell as such. PS doesn't let you do soemthing in IIS you can't do any other way.

Comment: @Scepticalist We have a process where we create AppPools and Websites using Powershell. But my main question is whether it's possible to assign different certificates on websites using the same port number?

Comment: Can you do it in IIS? If it's not possible then it wont be possible in PS either

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background Rather simple to achieve via SNI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You need to set different host name for each site so that the site can be accessed by `https://hostname:443`, not `https://localhost:443` or `https://serverIP:443`.

When setting binding of the site, check the Require Server Name Indication.
[image]

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485834/register-a-https-binding-with-sni-enabled-in-iis-8-with-powershell-script